# Expecting Sequelize transaction to wait for callback function

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

Here I am working with Nodejs and Mysql. And using Sequelize module as ORM.
And I am Using transactions for my need and Inside transactions I need to call another api and based on response I have to proceed further or commit the transactions. **Problem is transaction not waiting for API response**. Here I am adding some code snippets...

```
var errorcheck = true;
models.sequelize.transaction().then( function ( t ) {}).then( function () {
    return models.Task.find( {
        where: { "id": 1 },
        include: [{
            model: models.Evaluation,
            include : [
                {
                    model: models.EvalForm,
                    attributes : ['id','name']
                },
                {
                    model: models.Clarification,
                    attributes : ['id','status']
                }
            ]
        },{
            model: models.User,
            include: [{
                model : models.User,
                as: 'Manager',
                attributes : ["id","ManagerId","name"],
                include : [{
                    model : models.User,
                    as: 'Manager',
                    attributes : ["id","ManagerId","name"]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }).then(function(task) {
        // new API
        client.post('api/saveEval/', finalevalObj, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if(body.resCode==="OK"){
                return finaltaskobj.Evaluation.updateAttributes(finalevalUpObj, { transaction: t }).then(function (data2) {

                }).catch(function (err) { errorcheck = false; return res.send({ "error": { "code": 5000, "message": err.message } }) });
            }else{
                errorcheck = false;
                errors.push(body.msg);
            }
        });


    }).then(function ( definitions ) {
        if(errorcheck){
            return t.commit();
        }else{
            return t.rollback()
        };
    });
}).then( function () {
    if(errorcheck){
       //Now Here I am calling new API. And working fine. I know this is not better way of doing.
       return res.send({"resCode":"OK"});   
    }else{
        return res.send({"resCode":"ERROR"});
    };
}, function (err) {
    return res.send({"error":{"code": 5000,"message": err.message}});
});
```

Like this I have so many updates before and after calling new API. But transaction commits before getting response from new API. I understood I have to do something to wait  transaction. Some where I am using "models.sequelize.Promise.map" for iteration purpose and working fine. Do I have any other method like that. Please help me by improving same code.

Thanks for great help......